# When looping through animations, only the last loop runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-animate, progress-bar

This is a follow up from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885144/).

I have a [progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) circle that animates on scroll. If there is just one circle it works as expected.

Now I want to create many of these animated circles by looping through an object with different key-values pairs.

For example:

```
  var divsValues = {
    'total-score-circle': 0.75, 
    'general-score-circle': 0.80, 
    'speed-score-circle': 0.85, 
    'privacy-score-circle': 0.90,
  };
```

For each key-value pair, the key is a div ID and the value is number that tells the animation how far to go.

Below is the code where I try to implement my loop, but the problem is that **only the last circle is animated on scroll**. All the circles appear in their "pre-animation" state, but only the last circle actually becomes animated when you scroll to the bottom.

I need each circle to animate once it is in the viewport.

```js
//Loop through my divs and create animated circle for each one
function makeCircles() {
  var divsValues = {
    'total-score-circle': 0.75,
    'general-score-circle': 0.80,
    'speed-score-circle': 0.85,
    'privacy-score-circle': 0.90,
  };

  for (var i in divsValues) {
    if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      bgCircles(i, divsValues[i]);
    }
  }
}
makeCircles();

// Check if element is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
  var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

//Circle design and animation
function bgCircles(divid, countvalue) {
  // Design the circle using progressbar.js
  bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(document.getElementById(divid), {
    color: '#ddd',
    // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
    // prevent clipping
    strokeWidth: 4,
    trailWidth: 4,
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 1400,
    text: {
      autoStyleContainer: false
    },
    from: {
      color: '#ddd',
      width: 4
    },
    to: {
      color: '#888',
      width: 4
    },
    // Set default step function for all animate calls
    step: function(state, circle) {
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

      var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
      if (value === 0) {
        circle.setText('');
      } else {
        circle.setText(value + '%');
      }
    }
  });
  bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Montserrat", sans-serif';
  bar.text.style.fontSize = '1.7rem';
  bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
  bar.path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

  //Animate the circle when scrolled into view
  window.onscroll = function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(jQuery('#' + divid))) bar.animate(countvalue);
    else bar.animate(0); // or bar.set(0)
  }
}
```

```css
#total-score-circle,
#general-score-circle,
#speed-score-circle,
#privacy-score-circle {
  margin: 0.8em auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>

<div id="total-score-circle"></div>
<div id="general-score-circle"></div>
<div id="speed-score-circle"></div>
<div id="privacy-score-circle"></div>
```

---

While researching this problem I learned that JavaScript will only output the last value of a loop, which I thought could be the cause of my problem.

So I tried to replace the for loop with [these solutions](https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value)...

**Solution 1:** Same problem as before, only the last loop animates on scroll.

```
  for (var i in divsValues) {
    (function(){
      var ii = i;
        if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
          bgCircles(ii, divsValues[ii]);
        }
    })();        
  }
```

**Solution 2:** Again, same problem as before, only the last loop animates on scroll.

```
  for (var i in divsValues) {
    let ii = i;
      if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
        bgCircles(ii, divsValues[ii]);
      }
  }
```

**Solution 3:** Again, same problem as before, only the last loop animates on scroll.

```
  for (var i in divsValues) {
    try{throw i}
    catch(ii) {
      if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
        bgCircles(ii, divsValues[ii]);
      }
    }
  }
```

So now I'm thinking maybe the problem is not the loop, but something I can't see or figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You were quite close.

Here are the fixes:

---

In the `function bgCircles(...)`, use `var` to declare the `bar` in that [function's scope](https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/):

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(document.getElementById(divid), {
```

---

When you set *the animate scrolled into view* checker event, you assign a new function over-and-over to `window.onscroll`. Since you are using jQuery, consider [jQuery's .scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler and use it like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(jQuery('#' + divid))) bar.animate(countvalue);
    else bar.animate(0); // or bar.set(0)
});
```

---

## The solution in whole:

```js
//Loop through my divs and create animated circle for each one
function makeCircles() {
  var divsValues = {
    'total-score-circle': 0.75,
    'general-score-circle': 0.80,
    'speed-score-circle': 0.85,
    'privacy-score-circle': 0.90,
  };

  for (var i in divsValues) {
    if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      bgCircles(i, divsValues[i]);
    }
  }
}
makeCircles();

// Check if element is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
  var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

//Circle design and animation
function bgCircles(divid, countvalue) {
  // Design the circle using progressbar.js
  var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(document.getElementById(divid), {
    color: '#ddd',
    // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
    // prevent clipping
    strokeWidth: 4,
    trailWidth: 4,
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 1400,
    text: {
      autoStyleContainer: false
    },
    from: {
      color: '#ddd',
      width: 4
    },
    to: {
      color: '#888',
      width: 4
    },
    // Set default step function for all animate calls
    step: function(state, circle) {
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

      var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
      if (value === 0) {
        circle.setText('');
      } else {
        circle.setText(value + '%');
      }
    }
  });
  bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Montserrat", sans-serif';
  bar.text.style.fontSize = '1.7rem';
  bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
  bar.path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

  //Animate the circle when scrolled into view
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(jQuery('#' + divid))) bar.animate(countvalue);
    else bar.animate(0); // or bar.set(0)
  });
}
```

```css
#total-score-circle,
#general-score-circle,
#speed-score-circle,
#privacy-score-circle {
  margin: 0.8em auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>

<div id="total-score-circle"></div>
<div id="general-score-circle"></div>
<div id="speed-score-circle"></div>
<div id="privacy-score-circle"></div>
```

---

## Note:

Since **I didn't edit any of your circle animation/circle visibility checking functions, I assume you intended the current state** of your *animate-when-scrolled-and-in-view* functionality the way, that it is right now. In this current state, your script **does/has the following side-effects**:

- If you don't scroll the page, not at all, your circles won't start to animate, even, when they are visible. **Solution: encapsulate the visibility checker lines to a separate function and run, when creating the circles.**
- If you scroll through a circle, its animation with the percent will going to go to its default state, which is 0%. **Solution: change the visibility checker function, when the particular element is not visible because of overscroll, return that state as visible too. This way your circles will stay at 100%, even when you scroll over them.**

---

### Regarding performance and best practices:

- When using jQuery, make sure to call `jQuery(...)` or its shorthand `$(...)` as few times as possible. **Use variables to store elements, properties, and data.**
- It's better to separate longer/larger, **monolithic functions into smaller functions** with a more narrow, but also more clear scope of functionality.
- When using event listeners, make sure to run as few of them as possible. Structure your HTML and your JavaScript code to have **clear and performant ways to access and modify your crucial elements, properties, and data**.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am trying to get rid of the first side effect you mentioned... if the circle is visible on page load I want it to animate immediately, not wait until there is a scroll. While the circles outside the onload viewport should be animated once scrolled into view. I tried your solution of encapsulating the visibility checker and running that function when creating the circles, but the circles that are visible on page load still need a scroll before animation. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z51h89wy/17/

Comment: You're welcome! I see, you need a slight refactoring and it's gonna be okay. If you cannot solve the problem the way you want it, please create another question with a well-structured and clearly phrased question. That way, others will see the full solution in the future. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The loop you have will run so fast that the browser engine wont be able to render the changes, I would suggest either you use `setInterval()` method or continuous `setTimeout()` method which will add some delay to your code so that the browser can render the changes you are making.

For your special case I would suggest:

```
var i = 0;
var tobecleared = setInterval(timer,1000);

function timer(){
    var p = get_ith_key_from_divsvalues(i);//implement this method
    console.log(p);
    bgCircles(p, divsValues[p]);
    i++;
    if(i == Object.keys(divsValues).length)
         clearInterval(tobecleared);
}
function get_ith_key_from_divsvalues(i){
     var j = -1;
     for(var property in divsValues){
          j++;
          if(j==i)
                return property;
     }
}
```

**Note :** `window.onscroll` is being overwritten in each call that is why only the last circle responds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you elaborate what you mean by `implement this method`? I only just started learning JS and I'm not sure what I am supposed to do with that function.

Comment: function get_ith_key_from_divsvalues(int i){
     var j = 0;
     for(var property in divsValues){
          if(j==i)
                return property;
          j++;
     }
}

Comment: Are you saying pull the divsValues object out of the function and use your delay below that? I tired it here but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/yvo1rpk9/

Comment: Debugging is a hard thing to do my friend, i would suggest print all the suspected values and see where is it lacking, i am trying too.

Comment: I debugged my code, there were some typos. I commented your function call and ran the code in my terminal it outputs in an expected way.

Comment: I ran your jsfiddle code with my degugged code inserted in it. It outputs 4 translucent kind of circles one by one in every one second.

Comment: Thanks, I made an updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvo1rpk9/4/. There is still the original problem, only the last circle animated on scroll. None of the others animate. Only change is that each circle appears in a delayed fashion. Appreciate the help, but maybe the problem is something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173288/discussion-between-tinytiger-and-anurag-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

There are two fixes you need to apply.

1. Currently `bar` is the global variable, so it's always the same, to fix it declare it with `var`.
2. Use [window.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) to attach scroll event to window, by setting handler with window.onscroll you constantly override event handler and usage of addEventListener allow you attach more than one event handler.

```js
//Loop through my divs and create animated circle for each one
$( document ).ready(function(){
function makeCircles() {
  var divsValues = {
    'total-score-circle': 0.75,
    'general-score-circle': 0.80,
    'speed-score-circle': 0.85,
    'privacy-score-circle': 0.90,
  };

  for (var i in divsValues) {
    if (divsValues.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      bgCircles(i, divsValues[i]);
    }
  }
}
makeCircles();

// Check if element is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
  var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

//Circle design and animation
function bgCircles(divid, countvalue) {
  // Design the circle using progressbar.js
  var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(document.getElementById(divid), {
    color: '#ddd',
    // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
    // prevent clipping
    strokeWidth: 4,
    trailWidth: 4,
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 1400,
    text: {
      autoStyleContainer: false
    },
    from: {
      color: '#ddd',
      width: 4
    },
    to: {
      color: '#888',
      width: 4
    },
    // Set default step function for all animate calls
    step: function(state, circle) {
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

      var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
      if (value === 0) {
        circle.setText('');
      } else {
        circle.setText(value + '%');
      }
    }
  });
  bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Montserrat", sans-serif';
  bar.text.style.fontSize = '1.7rem';
  bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
  bar.path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

  //Animate the circle when scrolled into view
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(jQuery('#' + divid))) bar.animate(countvalue);
    else bar.animate(0); // or bar.set(0)
  })
}
})
```

```css
#total-score-circle,
#general-score-circle,
#speed-score-circle,
#privacy-score-circle {
  margin: 0.8em auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>

<div id="total-score-circle"></div>
<div id="general-score-circle"></div>
<div id="speed-score-circle"></div>
<div id="privacy-score-circle"></div>
```